# React Native Paper Icons repository

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper, material-design-icons

I have struggled a lot to figure out the repository being used in react native paper for Icons, using react native paper designing APP becomes very easy but figuring out Icon names was a bit struggle.

Comment: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/icons.html

Answer (score 3):

React Native Paper uses Material Community Icons as default, it is a bit difficult to figure out the Icon names, below is the CDN URL for cheatsheet, just remove **mdi-** from any icon name at Valla it works!!

https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/5.4.55/

example:- in cheatsheet name is **mdi-comment-outline**, remove **mdi-** from this name thats it!!

```
<List.Item
    title="First Item"
    description="Item description"
    left={props => <List.Icon {...props} icon="comment-outline" />}
  />
```

Comment: More visible site: https://materialdesignicons.com
And conversion still works, for example: 'mdiAcountPlus' -> 'account-plus'

Answer (score 1):

It uses **Material Design Icons** as an icon library, if you want to add icons then this technique will definitely work:

1. Visit https://materialdesignicons.com/
2. Click on any icon, and above there will be import Statement/Line for eg like: `import { mdiAccountSchool } from '@mdi/js';`.
3. just convert `mdiAccountSchool` => `account-school`.

**This will definitely work!**

Answer (score 0):

I use this site  : https://materialdesignicons.com/

Need to wait a few seconds then all icons will show
Good search bar for quick searching